# convert data into string js

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a webpage i download and put into an iframe, to get the contents of a div off of the page. When I get the text from the div and compare it to a string it does not show the variable(which is now the text of a div from the iframe) as a string. I don't know what the webpage uses to populate the div with the text. How can I make the variable a into a string to compare it within an if statment?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init(){
     var frame = document.getElementById("frame");
     frame.src = "saved.html";
     var innerDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
     var divs = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("div");
     if (divs.length == 83) {
          a = divs[34].innerHTML;
     }
     else {
          a = divs[33].innerHTML;
     }
     a = a.split(' ').join('');
     a = a.replace("<b>", "");
     a = a.replace("</b>", "");
     alert(a);
     if (a == "Text") {
          alert("same");
     }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
     <iframe id="frame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you seeing when you `alert(a)`? I would expect `a` to contain the entire HTML contained in the `div` element; it may contain something other than text, depending on that page. It may also contain unexpected whitespace inherited from the original HTML that would be stripped out on display; you may want to try `a.trim()`. I take it this is from a scraping application; you should consider that expecting content at a particular numbered position in the document is very brittle to future changes of the page format.

Comment: You should try waiting for the page to load.

Comment: alert(a) is the same as the string "Text", but it doesn't not alert "same". I will try trim and see what that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured otu the way to do this. create a textinput and place the variable as the value and retrieve the value of the text input object.

Answer (score 0):

You may use textContent instead of innerHtml
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent

Comment: If you are not worried about Internet Explorer prior to version 9, that is.   Things like this are why using a good JavaScript library is practically mandatory for sanity and efficiency.